# Why when i click delete it keeps an square?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm new in javascript and leaflet. I have a leaflet map with two tiff images. Each image has associated a layer with two buttons and a text, one button is to go to the image and other is to delete the image. when I click delete I want the associated layer to disappear as well, but it keeps a little square.

In this image you can see an image on the map and the two layers:
[image: Image on the map with two group layers]

When I click on delete, the image disappears and one of the layers becomes a square:

[image: Click on delete, no image and one of the layer is a square]

I want that the little square disappears too. How can i do it?

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 5);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var geoTIFFLayerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

function addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath, groupName) {
  fetch(imagePath)
    .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then(arrayBuffer => parseGeoraster(arrayBuffer))
    .then(georaster => {
      var layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
        georaster: georaster,
        opacity: 0.7,
        resolution: 256
      });
      layer.addTo(geoTIFFLayerGroup);

      var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, null, {
        collapsed: false
      }).addTo(map);

      // Add a checkbox to the layer control for each GeoTIFF layer
      layerControl.addOverlay(layer, groupName);

      // Add the custom button to the layer control
      var locationButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'custom-button');
      locationButton.innerHTML = 'Go to Image Location';
      locationButton.onclick = function() {
        map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());

      };
      layerControl.getContainer().appendChild(locationButton);

      // Add the custom button to the layer control
      var deleteButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'custom-button');
      deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete image';
      deleteButton.onclick = function() {
        if (layer) {
          map.removeLayer(layer);

          var container = layerControl.getContainer();
          container.removeChild(deleteButton);

          container.removeChild(locationButton);

          // Remove the layer from the layer group
          layerControl.removeLayer(layer);
          layerControl._update();
          geoTIFFLayerGroup.removeLayer(layer);
        }


      };
      layerControl.getContainer().appendChild(deleteButton);

      map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error loading image:', error));
}

// Replace 'path/to/your/image.tif' with the actual paths of your local images

var imagePath1 = 'Ortomosaico.tif';
var imagePath2 = 'example_4326.tif';

addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath1, 'GeoTIFF 1');
addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath2, 'GeoTIFF 2');
```

```css
#map {
  height: 500px;
}

.custom-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster-layer-for-leaflet"></script>
```

Comment: Right-click on the square and see if it is not something you forgot to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace your onclick with something like this:

```
deleteButton.onclick = function () {
  if (layer) {
    map.removeLayer(layer);
    map.removeControl(layerControl);
  }          
};
```

```js
        var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 5);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        var geoTIFFLayerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

        function addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath, groupName) {
            fetch(imagePath)
                .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
                .then(arrayBuffer => parseGeoraster(arrayBuffer))
                .then(georaster => {
                    var layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
                        georaster: georaster,
                        opacity: 0.7,
                        resolution: 256
                    });
                    layer.addTo(geoTIFFLayerGroup);

                    var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, null, { collapsed: false }).addTo(map);

                    // Add a checkbox to the layer control for each GeoTIFF layer
                    layerControl.addOverlay(layer, groupName);

                    // Add the custom button to the layer control
                    var locationButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'custom-button');
                    locationButton.innerHTML = 'Go to Image Location';
                    locationButton.onclick = function () {
                        map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());

                    };
                    layerControl.getContainer().appendChild(locationButton);

                    // Add the custom button to the layer control
                    var deleteButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'custom-button');
                    deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete image';
                    deleteButton.onclick = function () {
                        if (layer) {
                            map.removeLayer(layer);
                            map.removeControl(layerControl);
                        }


                    };
                    layerControl.getContainer().appendChild(deleteButton);

                    map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error loading image:', error));
        }

        // Replace 'path/to/your/image.tif' with the actual paths of your local images

        var imagePath1 = 'https://geotiff.github.io/georaster-layer-for-leaflet-example/example_4326.tif';
        var imagePath2 = 'https://geotiff.github.io/georaster-layer-for-leaflet-example/example_4326.tif?test';

        addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath1, 'GeoTIFF 1');
        addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath2, 'GeoTIFF 2');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 500px;
        }

        .custom-control {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            z-index: 1000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster-layer-for-leaflet"></script>
    
</body>

</html>
```